# Implementing client callback functionality in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server

The project I'm working on is a client-server application with all services written in WCF and the client in WPF. There are cases where the server needs to push information to the client. I initially though about using WCF Duplex Services, but after doing some research online, I figured a lot of people are avoiding it for many reasons.

The next thing I thought about was having the client create a host connection, so that the server could use that to make a service call to the client. The problem however, is that the application is deployed over the internet, so that approach requires configuring the firewall to allow incoming traffic and since most of the users are regular users, that might also require configuring the router to allow port forwarding, which again is a hassle for the user.

My third option is that in the client, spawns a background thread which makes a call to the `GetNotifications()` method on server. This method on the server side then, blocks until an actual notification is created, then the thread is notified (using an `AutoResetEvent` object maybe?) and the information gets sent to the client. The idea is something like this:

**Client**

```
private void InitializeListener()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var notification = server.GetNotifications();

            // Display the notification.
        }
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

**Server**

```
public NotificationObject GetNotifications()
{
    while (true)
    {
         notificationEvent.WaitOne();
         return someNotificationObject;
    }
}

private void NotificationCreated()
{
    // Inform the client of this event.
    notificationEvent.Set();
}
```

In this case, `NotificationCreated()` is a callback method called when the server needs to send information to the client.

What do you think about this approach? Is this scalable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each client you are going to hold a thread on the server. If you have a few hundred clients and the server wouldn't use the memory anyway, that may be fine. If there can be more clients, or you do not wish to burn 1MB of stack per client, you should make some changes:

1. Use an async WCF action method. They allow you to unblock the request thread while the method is waiting.
2. Change the event model to an async once. `SemaphoreSlim` has async support. You can also use `TaskCompletionSource`.

That way you can scale up to *many* connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The clients are using .NET 4.0, so can't support `async` at this point. Could you elaborate more on the second one? Not sure what you mean by `Change the event model to an async once.`.

Comment: 1: Client and server are 100% separated over a binary network protocol. One can use async, the other can do whatever it wants including running on a wrist watch programmed in C or not using async. Was that clear?; 2: if you block on an event on the server, you are holding up a thread (see my answer for what that means). So you don't want to wait on events. `SemaphoreSlim.WaitOneAsync` allows you to logically wait while not blocking a thread. Research a bit how that works and how that plays together with WCF async actions.

Comment: Will do a research on it. Thanks mate.